# Javafx - Missing Modena.css - Can't See Some Components

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, java-web-start, jnlp

I created a jar with manifest and jnlp file, and I'm hosting it over apache on a local machine of mine. When I run `javaws thefile.jnlp`, it launches the program as expected, downloading the `.jar` from my local server (not `localhost`, but a server on my home network), but it doesn't display properly.

[image: Examplar]

`javafx.scene.control.Label` doesn't appear at all (text not visible, and takes no space), `javafx.scene.control.TextField` borders aren't showing (in the picture, to the right of Order #, that bar is the cursor, and is in a `TextField`, but the border around it doesn't show). And the black space on the right is a scrollbar. There is another invisible one at the bottom. It works, but is not visible, and a few other problems.

The output from `javaws` is:

```
lmat@ryle~/Downloads$ javaws landmansoftware.jnlp 
Codebase matches codebase manifest attribute, but application is unsigned. Continuing. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/no_redeploy.html for details.
Sep 09, 2015 9:35:06 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css" not found.
Sep 09, 2015 9:35:06 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena-no-transparency.css" not found.
Sep 09, 2015 9:35:06 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena-no-transparency.css" not found.
Sep 09, 2015 9:35:06 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css" not found.
Sep 09, 2015 9:35:06 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena-no-transparency.css" not found.
lmat@ryle~/Downloads$
```

My hunch is that those "not found" css files have something to do with this. I've tried lots of things to reference `jfxrt.jar` where those css files are found, to no avail.

It is important to note that this works and looks fine when I run `java -jar Text.jar`.

Perhaps the application is trying to find those `.css`es over the same channel that it retrieved the `.jar` file (over the network, over apache)? Of course, they're not exposed over the network, only the `.jar` is.

I will appreciate any information that may lead to an answer!

Comment: The jar will be downloaded and after that it will run on your local Java installation. Which version of JRE you are using? And which you where using for compiling?

Comment: I just installed all my javas (jdk, webstart, javafx, etc.) yesterday on server and client, both archlinux. They're both on java8. `jar tf /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar` reveals the css files on the client as expected.

Comment: My guess is that you don't have sufficient permissions to read the content of the jar URL that points to `modena.css` (or `modena.bss`). This is a guess though. The code in the `StyleManager` deliberately squashes some error information in this case, to avoid leaking anything that shouldn't be seen if running without permissions. Maybe try opening a connection to the URL `getClassLoader().getResource("com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css")` directly and try to read something, and log any exception you get.

Comment: This was my second guess too, but to be sure it is a permisson problem, please post the content of your jnlp and of your manifest file. Both need in an unsigned context some special settings. For settings of manifest file you may have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/manifest.html) and for jnlp structure [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html)

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the suggestion. When I run `java -jar Client.jar`, I can read the `modena.css` resource as expected. However, when I run the same jar using javaws and the jnlp, I get the `ClassLoader`, but the call to `getResource` returns `null`. Same code. http://sprunge.us/jNYd Now what?

Comment: @NwDx The jnlp can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/p/lawsa/gitrepo/ci/master/tree/test/javafxexample/web/client.jnlp, and manifest here: https://sourceforge.net/p/lawsa/gitrepo/ci/master/tree/test/javafxexample/client/manifest Both of these files are in an example project that illustrates my problem. It does take a while to set up, though...configuring apache, adjusting all my server entries, etc.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement You haven't set any permisson level in both files. So javaws will fall back to default security level where the app isn't able to open any system resources on the running client. You need to set the levels to `all-permissions` in both files. And you should sign your jar, even with a self-signed certificate. After that, your App should run with only a warning that the certificate isn't trusted and maybe you need to add the url to your trusted url's in java preferences.